Folder Titles & Screen Background Lost After 24.04 Update
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
~$ uname -a
Linux inspiron-5567 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 21:40:26 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

CPU: i5-7xxx
RAM: 16 GB
Graphics Compositor: X11
Something odd started this afternoon.
I updated this morning but these were just routine updates - no change to Ubuntu version or kernel. Opening the Trash I saw missing characters for the filenames and the window headings.
On restarting I found that my desktop background image (Noble Numbat graphic) was gone and desktop details like the clock was missing all digits bar the second digits.

The file explorer had folder names missing or garbled.

What the hell has gone wrong here ?
I suppose I should thank the heavens that my icons and the rest of it has been rendered properly.
But what is it with the desktop and file explorer rendering process ?
For the record, Wayland is disabled so that flickering observed in Firefox and Thunderbird be eliminated.
EDIT
I restored my 24.04.1 to its state yesterday morning and it's booted up fine.
But problem now is I fear doing any updates till I am sure the bad updates are not included . . .
EDIT 2
The offending update is among those from apt.
We can ignore the warp-terminal update. That leaves 8 graphics related updates.
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for sandbar: 
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2.3/ubuntu noble InRelease              
Hit:5 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease   
Ign:7 https://releases.warp.dev/linux/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:9 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.2.3 noble InRelease                   
Hit:10 https://releases.warp.dev/linux/deb stable Release                      
Hit:11 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
12 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
sandbar@inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0
  libxatracker2 mesa-libgallium mesa-vulkan-drivers warp-terminal
9 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 64.4 MB of archives.

My main suspect is the oibaf graphics drivers so I removed this from the updates repos.
EDIT 3
Suspect confirmed. All well after new updates applied.
Confirm likely cause of issue to be buggy drivers from oibaf repo.

Fonts missing? Locale misgonfigurartion?

I see no missing fonts and my region, languages and keyboards are as per I configged them after 24.04.1 installation.

My Tweaks seem to be fine now. But maybe one of the system updates had a bug that screwed up the folder titles somehow. I will be very conservative in updating for some time !

Turned out to be graphics drivers from the that were buggy from the repo: ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf  No alternative but exclude these from normal updates.
